# Servlet not working in EJB Project in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, ejb, wildfly, ear, java-ee-7

I'm new in Intellij IDEA and I created a test Java EE project in it. First of all in New Project I selected Java Enterprise (Java JDK 7) and added the additional Libraries:

- Web Application (3.1)
- EJB: Enterprise Java Beans (3.2 without ejb-jar.xml)
- Java EE Application (Java EE 7)

The app created successfully. Then I created the Stateless Java Class:

```
package test.server;

import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;


@Stateless(name = "TestClientEJB")
@LocalBean
public class TestClientBean {
    public TestClientBean() {
    }

    public String getHello() {
        return "Hello EJB from Intellij";
    }

}
```

and after it created Servlet:

```
package test.client;

import test.server.TestClientBean;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

@WebServlet(name = "ClientServlet")
public class ClientServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    TestClientBean testClientBean;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print(testClientBean.getHello());
    }
}
```

As a Application Server I use WildFly 8.1 Final. I setup it with EAR Artifact and it give the URL as:

```
http://localhost:8080/EJBTestWeb/
```

when I run it in browser, it show me what I write in index.jsp. but when I write type

```
http://localhost:8080/EJBTestWeb/ClientServlet
```

it show me Not Found message. where is the problem? All needed Jars I downloaded

Answer (score 0):

It's worked when in Servlet I changed

```
@WebServlet(name = "ClientServlet")
```

to

```
@WebServlet("/ClientServlet")
```